# Number of elements in a squared set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $S= \{\emptyset, 5, \{1,5\}\}$, how many elements does $S^2$ have?

The answer to this question was given to be $9$, as $S$ has three elements so $S^2$ will have $9$, however, for example, by the principles of a cartesian product, there will be an element in which $\emptyset$ is multiplied by $\emptyset$, which I understand just to be $\emptyset$, which would mean that there would be less than $9$ elements.

Is my understanding flawed and there are indeed $9$ elements?

Comment: Can you quote which principle of a cartesian product you are referring to? It would appear you have a misunderstanding.

Comment: "There will be an element in which $\emptyset$ is **multiplied by** $\emptyset$"  uhm... no?  Nothing is being multiplied here...  there are only things being put into pairs.

Comment: Ah that would be it. Thanks

Comment: Take for smaller example $\color{red}{A=\{\emptyset,1\}}$ and $\color{blue}{B=\{2,\{3\}\}}$.  One would have $\color{red}{A}\times\color{blue}{B}=\{(\color{red}{\emptyset},\color{blue}{2}),(\color{red}{\emptyset},\color{blue}{\{3\}}),(\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{2}),(\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{\{3\}})\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cartesian product merely assembles the elements of two sets in order. Here's is an excerpt from Wikipedia:

> ... for sets $A$ and $B$, the Cartesian product $A \times B$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(a, b)$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

In your specific example, the product will consist of the nine pairs $(\varnothing,\varnothing),(\varnothing,5),(\varnothing,\{1,5\}), (5,\varnothing), (5,5), (5, \{1,5\}), (\{1,5\},\varnothing), (\{1,5\}, 5),$ and $(\{1,5\},\{1,5\})$.

In general, the notion of "multiplication" between set elements is ill-defined.